# sorting filenames numerically when they have non-numeric prefix

Tags: bash, rename, sort

I have files in the following format: `x1 x2 ... x10 x11 ... x101 ...`

I want to rename these files, so they all have the same name length: `x001 x002 ... x010 ...`

I can do this with files, that don't have the non-numeric prefix (just using `sort -n` followed by a `while read x;`), but sort doesn't recognize the numeric value, when it's not on the beginning of the file-name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try sorting the files using the `v` (version) option of `ls` e.g.  `ls -1v`. Or you can use numeric sort with `x` as the delimiter:  `ls | sort -n -t 'x' +1`

But you don't have to sort the files to rename them. You can just look at the length of the file name and pad it with zeros if necessary. Here is a small script which does that:

```
prefix=x
maxLength=4

for file in ${prefix}*
do
 if [ ${#file} -lt $maxLength ]
 then
     newFile=$file
     while [ ${#newFile} -lt $maxLength ]
     do
       newFile=${newFile/$prefix/${prefix}0}
     done   
     mv $file $newFile
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you need to sort them first?

```
m=0
for f in x*; do
  [ "${#f}" -gt "$m" ] &&
    m=${#f}
done

for f in x*; do
  echo mv -- "$f" "${f%${f#?}}$( printf '%0.*d' $(( m - 1 )) "${f#?}" )"
done
```

If your printf implementation 
doesn't support the syntax above, 
use `printf "%0.$(( m - 1 ))d" "${f#?}"`.

Remove echo when satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

Just to elaborate on dogbane's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16943/86986), `sort` has a version-sort option. Note that some platforms (e.g. busybox) do not have this option.

You can use it like so:

```
sort -V
sort --version-sort
```

Or to version sort the n'th column:

```
sort -knV
```

Answer (score 2):

You need rename, while there are similar tools, which could serve you too:

```
touch x1 x2 x10 x11 x101 
ls ; rename 's/x/x0/' x[0-9]
```

> x1  x10  x101  x11  x2

```
ls ; rename 's/x/x0/' x[0-9][0-9]
```

> x01  x02  x10  x101  x11

```
ls
```

> x001  x002  x010  x011  x101

'rename' is part of some perl package, if you need to install it, at least available for Linux.

Without rename, there is a similar solution with a loop:

```
rm * 
touch x1 x2 x10 x11 x101
for f in  x[0-9] ; do mv $f ${f/x/x0}; done 
for f in  x[0-9][0-9] ; do mv $f ${f/x/x0}; done ; ls
```

> x001  x002  x010  x011  x101